# How to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[How to tell Adobe Illustrator to use a font of a slightly different name?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/63147/1297)

Got downvoted, so I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what since the downvoter left no comments.

Comment: My guess is that it's a technical question and not a design question. I voted to migrate it to SuperUser as such

Comment: @ZachSaucier Oh, I specifically didn't put it there, thinking it was more appropriate here.

Comment: @ZachSaucier It's really NOT a SuperUser question. It's actually a common issue among print designers...! Replacing font in a software has nothing of technical support. It's quite common to have to deal with different variant of a same font and having to update a whole document this way. The proof is the functionality is IN most design software! Plus it's very good info for the graphic design stack and should be basic knowledge! So at worse, it's a beginner question but apparently it was worth asking as an experienced designer commented it was new to him/her!